# Converting an array/vector of double to alglib complex

Tags: c++, arrays, converters, complex-numbers, alglib

I'm creating a project to filter signals. At present, it only takes real input values, however, to do the filtering using the `alglib` library it needs to take `alglib::complex` types. Therefore the `double[]` input needs to be converted

In the [reference manual](http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.cpp.html#gs_global) its states these are double precision complex types. Is there a way to simply copy the data across - as the only alternative seems to be allocating elementwise, or creating a very large string and allocating directly to the complex array.

Two methods I have found of allocating to an array so far include;

```
alglib::complex complex_arr = "[3, 2, 1]"; //Method 1 string assignment
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) { //Method 2 elementwise assignment
            complex_arr[i] = (complex) double_arr[i];
        }
```